# RxJS "throw new Error" vs "Observable.throw"

Tags: error-handling, rxjs

Is there a difference between `throw new Error()` and `Observable.throw()` and if so what is it? Obviously since `Observable.throw` exists there is some reason for it, but besides a shorter stack trace I could not find any differences.

[Here's an example](https://jsbin.com/vegoqiziju/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Observable.throw` returns an error when in streams. For example I am expecting an `Observable` but for some reason, I want to return an error. These cases its not possible to use `throw new Error()` .

For example:

```
var source = someStream$
    .flatMap(data => data?
             Rx.Observable.of(data): // Or any other async operation 
             Rx.Observable.throw('invalid data'));
```

Here `flatMap` expects an Observable stream, if we need to use `throw new Error()` we need to do a hack .

It might have other advantages also to work well with the rx operators,that I am not aware of .